# 16.04.1 will not boot

Tags: 16.04

Running on Xenserver 6.5 need to reboot the VM and now I get a black screen then the VM just shuts down.

Machine was shut down via a shutdown command on the Ubuntu side.

Any hints?

Comment: Is this a reapeatable problem? If you reinstall and reboot, does it happen again? Which release of Ubuntu are you running? What steps have you taken to diagnose the problem? All these may help us answer your question without trying to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: Yes it happens every time when you boot this VM.  This machine has been up for months.  No patches were applied to it.  I have not reinstalled.  Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to recover.  Reinstalling Grub did not resolve.  Ended up moving the application to another machine and shutting down this vm.